# lollipop plot with sorting within group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a lollipop plot with a dataset that looks something like this:

```
set.seed(123)
example_df <- data.frame(strategy = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 2)), 
                         mt_equip = as.factor(rep(c('r', 'v'), times = 5)), 
                         cc = as.factor(c('cc', 'cc', 'no_cc', 'no_cc', 'part_cc', 'part_cc', 'cc', 'cc', 'no_cc', 'no_cc')), 
                         vt = as.factor(c(rep('d10', 4), rep('d1+d10', 2), rep('d1', 4))), 
                         model_ouput = rnorm(10)
                         )
example_df
   strategy mt_equip      cc     vt model_ouput
1         A        r      cc    d10 -0.56047565
2         A        v      cc    d10 -0.23017749
3         B        r   no_cc    d10  1.55870831
4         B        v   no_cc    d10  0.07050839
5         C        r part_cc d1+d10  0.12928774
6         C        v part_cc d1+d10  1.71506499
7         D        r      cc     d1  0.46091621
8         D        v      cc     d1 -1.26506123
9         E        r   no_cc     d1 -0.68685285
10        E        v   no_cc     d1 -0.44566197
```

My goal is to make a lollipop plot so that:

1. they are grouped and colored by `cc`, with `mt_equip` as the `shape` specification.
2. within each `cc` category, the lollipops are sorted from lowest to highest.
3. the lollipops should be separated and not entangled like in the figure shown.

I tried the `geom_lollipop()` option from the `ggalt` package as follows:

```
library(ggalt)

option2 <- ggplot(data = example_df, 
       aes(x = reorder(cc, model_ouput))) + 
    geom_lollipop(aes(y = model_ouput,
                   shape = mt_equip,
                   color = cc),
                  size = 5) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24)) 
plot(option2)
```

This is what I get:

[image]

How can I:

1. disentangle the lollipops so that each one stands alone within the `cc` group?
2. sort the disentangled lollipops in (1) from lowest to highest? I tried `reorder` but it did not produce the designed effect as shown in the image.
3. make the bars hollow for post-processing with color and stroke?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I haven't used `ggalt` but there doesn't seem to be any way for it to know that you want the lollipops separated. If it works like a normal `ggplot` geom, I think you need to both (a) specify a `group` aesthetic that has a unique value for each lollipop (perhaps add a unique `ID` column to your data for this since I think you want 1 lollipop per row, and (b) use something like `position = position_dodge()` to get them next to each other instead of on top of each other.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want for the order - `reorder` uses `mean` by default, and it indeed looks to me like red has the lowest mean, green is in the middle, and blue is the highest. If you want the colors mixed, then you'll need to *not* put `cc` on the x-axis, instead put a unique `ID` column on the x-axis and reorder *that* column.

Comment: As for the bars, they look to me like they are not bars but lines drawn with `geom_segment`... lollipop plots typically using thin lines with shapes at the end, not thick bars. If my assumption is right, "hollow bars" will probably take some hacking...

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas, I have created unique ids for each column and now the lollipops have been separated. I would like the plot to be ordered between and within the `cc` categories. Each `cc` category would be colored exactly as shown but ordered within each colored group, if that makes sense.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure how to control the order of the dodged bars. Would facets work? You could `reorder` by `ID`, put `ID` on the x axis, and use `facet_wrap(~cc, scales = "free_x")`

Comment: I've solved it now through your hints. I had to first group the data by `cc` and then used `dplyr::arrange` to sort the data by `model_output`. I set `.by_group = T` to group within the groups. Within the `geom_lollipop` call, I used `order` instead of `reorder` to sort the bars. It works perfectly now. Thank you for guiding me.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. It would make a nice community resource if you'd post that as an answer. I'm happy I was able to help without actually doing the experimentation and debugging :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon taking a few hints from @GregorThomas, I finally solved the problem with the following code:

```
library(ggalt)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
example_df <- data.frame(strategy = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 2)), 
                         mt_equip = as.factor(rep(c('r', 'v'), times = 5)), 
                         cc = as.factor(c('cc', 'cc', 'no_cc', 'no_cc', 'part_cc', 'part_cc', 'cc', 'cc', 'no_cc', 'no_cc')), 
                         vt = as.factor(c(rep('d10', 4), rep('d1+d10', 2), rep('d1', 4))), 
                         model_ouput = rnorm(10)
)



#the strategy variable is not unique so we make it so but combining two cols
example_df_mod <- example_df %>%
    unite(col = 'strategy', c(strategy, mt_equip), remove = F)

#make lollipop plot grouped by cc and sorted within each group 
option2 <- example_df_mod %>% 
    group_by(cc) %>% 
    arrange(model_ouput, .by_group = T) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(group = cc)) + 
    geom_lollipop(aes(x = order(cc, model_ouput), 
                      y = model_ouput,
                      shape = mt_equip,
                      color = cc),
                  size = 5) 
plot(option2)
```

[image]